# How to prevent any browser refresh function

Tags: user-interface, refresh, screen

what are all scenarios through which refresh happen on GUI? And 
How to prevent any browser refresh function (*examples*: 'F5' keystroke or refresh icon in screen, etc.... etc.... scenerios)

what I know is this....

```
document.onkeydown = function() {    
    switch (event.keyCode) { 
        case 116 : //F5 button
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false; 
        case 82 : //R button
            if (event.ctrlKey) { 
                event.returnValue = false; 
                event.keyCode = 0;  
                return false; 
            } 
    }
}
```

ANY OTHER SUGGESTIONS ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The refresh action is a *browser* function, not a *page* function, so you cannot override it from JavaScript running on a page. Just as an exercise, try figuring out how you would prevent the user from clicking the »Refresh« button (or going through the menu).